# Утечка памяти Python (threading)

Tags: python, многопоточность, память

Написал бота для твича, запускающий столько браузеров, сколько в txt строк с ссылками, передаёт им куки и редактирует локальное хранилище(всего пара данных). Даже если запустилось всего 2 потока, или три через какое то время скрипт падает с ошибкой недостачи памяти, почему?
p.s пробовал использовать tracemalloc, ничего не понял, но данные выгружу(для трёх потоков)
Диспетчер задач тоже всплеска не видит, хотя это возможно и не удивительно, там данные обновляются не так уж часто. Просто не понятно откуда утечка, ведь всё запускается и всё работает, а значит для работы памяти более чем хватает, а потом откуда то какой то мгновенный прикол прилетает..

***Ранее я не использовал потоки, а запускал одним питоном несколько копий другого питона, который делал почти тоже самое и там хоть 10 браузеров, всё работало.
Даже для теста сейчас оставил только один поток(оставил в url.txt одну ссылку), та же ошибка.***

```py
#импорт selenium
from selenium import webdriver
#импорт time , pickle
import time, pickle
#импорт потока
import threading

import tracemalloc

#проверяем есть ли куки
try:
    f = open('cookies.pkl', 'r')
    f.close()
    n=input("Куки найдены!\nНапиши 1, если хочешь продолжить, напиши 2 если хочешь перезаписать: ")
except:
    print("Куки не найдены, перезаписываем")
    n="2"
#перезаписываем
if n=="2":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/")
    input("\nЛогинься на твиче, а после нажми ENTER")
    cookie=driver.get_cookies()
    pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
    print("Куки сохранены, вырубай")
#тело, для потока
def threaded_func(q):
    #запускаем
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #агружаем предварительно для прогрузки формы и локального хранилища
    driver.get(q)
    #читаем куки
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        #удаляем строку с ошибкой
        if 'expiry' in cookie:
            del cookie['expiry']
        #загружаем куки
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    #js - звук
    driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('video-muted','{\"carousel\":true,\"default\":true}');")
    #js - качество
    driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('video-quality','{\"default\":\"160p30\"}');")
    #js - возраст
    driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('mature','true');")
    #js - "Начать"
    driver.execute_script("localStorage.setItem('channelPointsOnboardingDismissed','true');")
    #заходим
    driver.get(q)


    tracemalloc.start()
    # ... run your application ...
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
    print("\n\n\n\n\n")
    print("[ Top 10 ]")
    for stat in top_stats[:10]:
        print(stat)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n")



#Записываем в список значения из txt
with open('url.txt') as f:
    url = f.read().splitlines()
#сколько строк=столько потоков, чтобы пекарня не згорелась)
for q in url:
    #без этого ошибка будет, хз зачем это
    threads = []
    #заводим поток
    t = threading.Thread(target=threaded_func, args=(q,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Результат tracemalloc**

```
[ Top 10 ]












[ Top 10 ]
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tracemalloc.py:507
: size=412 B, count=1, average=412 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py:874:
size=304 B, count=1, average=304 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\_policybase.
py:303: size=116 B, count=3, average=39 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\_policybase.
py:301: size=114 B, count=3, average=38 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\message.py:1
21: size=40 B, count=1, average=40 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sele
nium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py:419: size=28 B, count=1, average=28 B

C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py:318
: size=27 B, count=1, average=27 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\feedparser.p
y:201: size=24 B, count=1, average=24 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\message.py:4
84: size=16 B, count=1, average=16 B












[ Top 10 ]
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tracemalloc.py:507
: size=412 B, count=1, average=412 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py:874:
size=304 B, count=1, average=304 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tracemalloc.py:65:
 size=256 B, count=8, average=32 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\_policybase.
py:303: size=232 B, count=6, average=39 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\_policybase.
py:301: size=228 B, count=6, average=38 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\message.py:1
21: size=80 B, count=2, average=40 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py:318
: size=54 B, count=2, average=27 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tracemalloc.py:185
: size=48 B, count=2, average=24 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\feedparser.p
y:201: size=48 B, count=2, average=24 B
C:\Users\Petrov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\message.py:4
84: size=32 B, count=2, average=16 B
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Куки найдены!
Напиши 1, если хочешь продолжить, напиши 2 если хочешь перезаписать: 1
[1127/155624.216:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
Initialize: No available renderers.
[1127/155624.218:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1057)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with
error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51958/devtools/browser/b403ebf5-051c-46f4-a
34c-1768aa6d25b4
[1127/155624.264:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQue
ryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
[1127/155625.276:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
Initialize: No available renderers.
[1127/155625.277:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1057)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with
error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[1127/155625.319:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQue
ryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51971/devtools/browser/b05b44cc-1d84-411d-9
df6-d0269cb09e26
[1127/155626.256:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
Initialize: No available renderers.
[1127/155626.256:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1057)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with
error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[1127/155626.308:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQue
ryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51993/devtools/browser/83eccd49-d5bb-4205-8
766-de8fc4625938
[1127/155652.473:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
PostSubBufferNV: Context lost.
[1127/155652.473:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(2672)] Context lost beca
use PostSubBuffer failed.
[1127/155652.473:ERROR:gpu_service_impl.cc(884)] Exiting GPU process because som
e drivers can't recover from errors. GPU process will restart shortly.
[1127/155652.476:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(259)] GetVSyncParameter
sIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.477:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.478:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
MakeCurrent: Context lost.
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
DestroySurface: display had a context loss
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1292)] eglDestroySurface failed with er
ror EGL_CONTEXT_LOST
[1127/155652.479:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
DestroyContext: display had a context loss
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(220)] eglDestroyContext failed with err
or EGL_CONTEXT_LOST
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
MakeCurrent: display had a context loss
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
MakeCurrent: display had a context loss
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1283)]   GLES2DecoderPas
sthroughImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1277)]   GLES2DecoderPas
sthroughImpl: Trying to make lost context current.
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
MakeCurrent: display had a context loss
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1283)]   GLES2DecoderPas
sthroughImpl: Context lost during MakeCurrent.
[1127/155652.480:ERROR:mf_helpers.cc(14)] Error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator
_win.cc on line 1045
[1127/155652.481:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(1277)]   GLES2DecoderPas
sthroughImpl: Trying to make lost context current.
[1127/155657.606:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
PostSubBufferNV: Context lost.
[1127/155657.606:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_passthrough.cc(2672)] Context lost beca
use PostSubBuffer failed.
[1127/155657.607:ERROR:gpu_service_impl.cc(884)] Exiting GPU process because som
e drivers can't recover from errors. GPU process will restart shortly.
[1127/155657.608:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(259)] GetVSyncParameter
sIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[1127/155657.608:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.609:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.609:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.609:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.610:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.610:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.611:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.611:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.611:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.612:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.612:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.613:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.613:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.614:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
Context has been lost.
[1127/155657.614:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
MakeCurrent: Context lost.
```

**Результат memory_profiler**

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30     17.5 MiB     17.5 MiB   @profile
    31                             def threaded_func(q):
    32                                  #запускаем
    33     17.6 MiB      0.1 MiB        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    34                                  #агружаем предварительно для прогрузки ф
ормы и локального хранилища
    35     17.6 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.get(q)
    36                                  #читаем куки
    37     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl"
, "rb"))
    38     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        for cookie in cookies:
    39                                          #удаляем строку с ошибкой
    40     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                if 'expiry' in cookie:
    41     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                        del cookie['expiry']
    42                                          #загружаем куки
    43     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    44                                  #js - звук
    45     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-muted','{\"carousel\":true,\"default\":true}');")
    46                                  #js - качество
    47     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-quality','{\"default\":\"160p30\"}');")
    48                                  #js - возраст
    49     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('mature','true');")
    50                                  #js - "Начать"
    51     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('channelPointsOnboardingDismissed','true');")
    52                                  #заходим
    53     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.get(q)


Filename: C:\Users\Petrov\Desktop\Bottwich4\cookies.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30     16.6 MiB     16.6 MiB   @profile
    31                             def threaded_func(q):
    32                                  #запускаем
    33     17.6 MiB      0.9 MiB        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    34                                  #агружаем предварительно для прогрузки ф
ормы и локального хранилища
    35     17.7 MiB      0.1 MiB        driver.get(q)
    36                                  #читаем куки
    37     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl"
, "rb"))
    38     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        for cookie in cookies:
    39                                          #удаляем строку с ошибкой
    40     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                if 'expiry' in cookie:
    41     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                        del cookie['expiry']
    42                                          #загружаем куки
    43     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    44                                  #js - звук
    45     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-muted','{\"carousel\":true,\"default\":true}');")
    46                                  #js - качество
    47     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-quality','{\"default\":\"160p30\"}');")
    48                                  #js - возраст
    49     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('mature','true');")
    50                                  #js - "Начать"
    51     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('channelPointsOnboardingDismissed','true');")
    52                                  #заходим
    53     17.6 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.get(q)


Filename: C:\Users\Petrov\Desktop\Bottwich4\cookies.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30     17.4 MiB     17.4 MiB   @profile
    31                             def threaded_func(q):
    32                                  #запускаем
    33     17.6 MiB      0.2 MiB        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    34                                  #агружаем предварительно для прогрузки ф
ормы и локального хранилища
    35     17.7 MiB      0.1 MiB        driver.get(q)
    36                                  #читаем куки
    37     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl"
, "rb"))
    38     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        for cookie in cookies:
    39                                          #удаляем строку с ошибкой
    40     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                if 'expiry' in cookie:
    41     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                        del cookie['expiry']
    42                                          #загружаем куки
    43     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    44                                  #js - звук
    45     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-muted','{\"carousel\":true,\"default\":true}');")
    46                                  #js - качество
    47     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('video-quality','{\"default\":\"160p30\"}');")
    48                                  #js - возраст
    49     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('mature','true');")
    50                                  #js - "Начать"
    51     17.7 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.execute_script("localStorage.setI
tem('channelPointsOnboardingDismissed','true');")
    52                                  #заходим
    53     17.6 MiB      0.0 MiB        driver.get(q)
```

**mprofile_20191127165610**

```
CMDLINE c:\users\petrov\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe cookies.py
MEM 0.777344 1574855770.9934
MEM 13.566406 1574855771.0934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.1934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.2934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.3934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.4934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.5934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.6934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.7934
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.8935
MEM 16.597656 1574855771.9935
MEM 17.359375 1574855772.0935
MEM 17.359375 1574855772.1935
MEM 17.359375 1574855772.2935
MEM 17.359375 1574855772.3935
MEM 17.359375 1574855772.4935
MEM 17.367188 1574855772.5935
MEM 17.429688 1574855772.6935
MEM 17.429688 1574855772.7995
MEM 17.429688 1574855772.8995
MEM 17.429688 1574855772.9995
MEM 17.488281 1574855773.0995
MEM 17.488281 1574855773.2345
MEM 17.488281 1574855773.3385
MEM 17.488281 1574855773.4385
MEM 17.488281 1574855773.5385
MEM 17.503906 1574855773.6386
MEM 17.503906 1574855773.7386
MEM 17.503906 1574855773.8386
MEM 17.503906 1574855773.9386
MEM 17.503906 1574855774.0386
MEM 17.558594 1574855774.1386
MEM 17.558594 1574855774.2386
MEM 17.558594 1574855774.3406
MEM 17.558594 1574855774.4406
MEM 17.558594 1574855774.5406
MEM 17.578125 1574855774.6406
MEM 17.632812 1574855774.7406
MEM 17.632812 1574855774.8406
MEM 17.632812 1574855774.9406
MEM 17.632812 1574855775.0406
MEM 17.640625 1574855775.1436
MEM 17.648438 1574855775.2466
MEM 17.648438 1574855775.3466
MEM 17.648438 1574855775.4467
MEM 17.671875 1574855775.5467
MEM 17.671875 1574855775.6467
MEM 17.671875 1574855775.7487
MEM 17.671875 1574855775.8487
MEM 17.671875 1574855775.9487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.0487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.1487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.2487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.3487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.4487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.5487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.6487
MEM 17.671875 1574855776.7487
MEM 17.687500 1574855776.8487
MEM 17.687500 1574855776.9487
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.0487
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.1488
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.2488
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.3488
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.4488
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.5538
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.6538
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.7618
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.8618
MEM 17.687500 1574855777.9618
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.0648
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.1648
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.3108
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.4108
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.5188
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.6188
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.7188
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.8188
MEM 17.687500 1574855778.9259
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.0259
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.1879
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.2909
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.3959
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.4969
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.5969
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.7079
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.8089
MEM 17.687500 1574855779.9089
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.0219
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.1249
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.2249
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.3259
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.4259
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.5259
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.6259
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.7290
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.8600
MEM 17.687500 1574855780.9870
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.0870
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.1920
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.2940
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.3940
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.5130
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.6530
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.8310
MEM 17.687500 1574855781.9830
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.1550
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.2550
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.3851
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.4851
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.5851
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.6991
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.8001
MEM 17.687500 1574855782.9101
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.0101
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.1851
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.3031
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.4031
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.5031
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.6031
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.7031
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.8181
MEM 17.687500 1574855783.9261
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.0501
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.1532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.2532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.3532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.4532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.5532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.6532
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.7542
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.8582
MEM 17.687500 1574855784.9582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.0582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.1582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.2582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.3582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.4582
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.5692
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.6692
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.7692
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.8692
MEM 17.687500 1574855785.9693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.0693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.1693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.2693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.3693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.4693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.5693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.6693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.7693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.8693
MEM 17.687500 1574855786.9693
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.0693
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.1693
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.2693
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.3703
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.4703
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.5703
MEM 17.687500 1574855787.6704
MEM 17.738281 1574855787.7704
MEM 17.738281 1574855787.8704
MEM 17.738281 1574855787.9704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.0704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.1704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.2704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.3704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.4704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.5704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.6704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.7704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.8704
MEM 17.738281 1574855788.9704
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.0704
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.1704
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.2704
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.3705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.4705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.5705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.6705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.7705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.8705
MEM 17.738281 1574855789.9705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.0705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.1705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.2705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.3705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.4705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.5705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.6705
MEM 17.738281 1574855790.7705
MEM 17.679688 1574855790.8705
MEM 17.679688 1574855790.9705
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.0705
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.1706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.2706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.3706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.4706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.5706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.6706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.7706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.8706
MEM 17.679688 1574855791.9706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.0706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.1706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.2706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.3706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.4706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.5706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.6706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.7706
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.8707
MEM 17.679688 1574855792.9717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.0717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.1717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.2717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.3717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.4717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.5717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.6717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.7717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.8717
MEM 17.679688 1574855793.9717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.0717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.1717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.2717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.3717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.4717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.5717
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.6728
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.7728
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.8728
MEM 17.679688 1574855794.9728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.0728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.1728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.2728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.3728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.4728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.5728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.6728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.7728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.8728
MEM 17.683594 1574855795.9728
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.0728
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.1728
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.2728
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.3729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.4729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.5729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.6729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.7729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.8729
MEM 17.683594 1574855796.9729
MEM 17.683594 1574855797.0729
MEM 17.683594 1574855797.1729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.2729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.3729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.4729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.5729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.6729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.7729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.8729
MEM 17.617188 1574855797.9729
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.0729
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.1730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.2730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.3730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.4730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.5730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.6730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.7730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.8730
MEM 17.617188 1574855798.9730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.0730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.1730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.2730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.3730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.4730
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.5800
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.6800
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.7800
MEM 17.617188 1574855799.8801
MEM 17.863281 1574855799.9801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.0801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.1801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.2801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.3801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.4801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.5801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.6801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.7801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.8801
MEM 17.863281 1574855800.9801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.0801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.1801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.2801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.3801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.4801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.5801
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.6802
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.7802
MEM 17.941406 1574855801.8802
MEM 17.988281 1574855801.9802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.0802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.1802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.2802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.3802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.4802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.5802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.6802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.7802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.8802
MEM 17.988281 1574855802.9802
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.0802
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.1802
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.2802
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.3803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.4803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.5803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.6803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.7803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.8803
MEM 17.988281 1574855803.9803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.0803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.1803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.2803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.3803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.4803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.5803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.6803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.7803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.8803
MEM 17.988281 1574855804.9813
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.0813
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.1814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.2814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.3814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.4814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.5814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.6814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.7814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.8814
MEM 17.988281 1574855805.9814
```

**А вот это запуск по отдельности(без потоков), немного подвисает но всё работает более чем исправно!**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Потому что вы запускаете очень много копий браузера?

Comment: А если без скрипта точно так же две-три копии браузера вручную запустить с нужными ссылками - что будет?

Comment: Ранее я не использовал потоки, а запускал несколько копий одной и той же программы(с разными url для браузера) и всё работало прекрасно, даже если штук 10 браузеров запускал

Comment: Сейчас попробовал оставить в url.txt только одну ссылку, получил ту же ошибку, от одного браузера уж явно ничего не должно крашиться) @andreymal